# When storing a User-Uploaded video file (such as .mp4) for a Rails (or PHP, ect.) CMS, how should I store the file?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, video, file-upload, content-management-system

Imagine I'm trying to start up a YouTube-style content management system (with Rails, PHP, or some other similar language or system) in which users can upload videos to my website (for others to view):

Should I store the file in a directory on the server or should I store the file in a database (or both)?

Should I do this in Ruby on Rails, PHP, or some other type of language?

Best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the file in a **directory** then store the ***filename/path*** in the **database**.

You could also consider using the cloud for storing these large files.

You could do that in **images, documents, or any other files**. That way, your database loads faster.

Comment: This is what I had intended to do and what I thought was the best practice. I just wanted to make sure because I didn't want to have to propagate a bunch of memory on my server unnecessarily. I will look into cloud storage. 

Thank You
- Donald